# Trouble inserting JSON data into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I created an sqlite3 database using python to store data as shown in the code below

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('tweets_data.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tweets')
cur.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE tweets (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, created_at TEXT, full_text TEXT, 
        favourite_count INTEGER, retweet_count INTEGER)
''')
```

With this table, i want to store data from a JSON file (parts of the code are screenshotted and attached as images), which i have loaded as seen below

```
import json

with open('tweets.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

After that, i tried inserting the data into the table using a for loop to pull out all unique tweet id and its following information. The code below is what i tried doing

```
for records in data:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (id, created_at, full_text, favourite_count, retweet_count) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                (records['id'], records['created_at'], records['full_text'], records['user']['favourites_count'], records['retweet_count']))
conn.commit()
print(cur.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

However when i did a print (cur.fetchall()), the output was only an empty list. Nothing was inserted into the table. Thank you if anybody is able to help!

[json file page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO4Ui.jpg)
[json file page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfBp9.jpg)

Comment: If possible then add json files in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cur.fetchall()` returns the result of the last query, and `INSERT` yields no result. You need a `SELECT`-query first:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tweets')
rows = cut.fetchall()
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you i am new to SQL so i am not completely sure on the queries. Thank you!